# Drupal CKeditor changed inline Image dialog

Tags: wysiwyg

Building a new site with Drupal 7.26 and the latest CKeditor library 4.3.2 (and CKEditor Module).
In the latest CKeditor Program the Image properties dialog has changed!

On CKeditor 4.0 the dialog looks like: [image: CKeditor 4.0 dialog]

On the CKeditor 4.3.2 the dialog looks like: [image: CKeditor 4.3.2 dialog]

How can I get the "Link" and "Advanced"  tabs back in 4.3.2 ???

Comment: I am still trying to understand but for me the first screenshot comes up when using full source of 4.3.2 only. The second screen comes up when the full source is packaged with CKEditor plugin 'Enhanced Image'